# Hidden rows in HTML table causing problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I Have an HTML table With JSON data which I am creating with Java-Script

What i am doing :-

- I have a Table which have column as col-span as required
- So each header have four columns under them
- I have a filter above my table so that user can select the column which they want to see
- For that i have an input-field with drop-down in side which i have all the column names which user can filter accordingly
- data is filtering properly

**Issue I am facing is :-**

- I am using below code to hide or show the columns

  ```
  $("#save").on("click", function() {
    // Get the selected classes
    var classes = $("#To")
      .val()
      .replace(/\s+/g, "")
      .split(","); // Hide cells
    $(".table thead tr:not(:first) th:not(:first-child)").hide();
    $(".table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").hide(); // Adjust thead first row colspans
    $(".table thead tr:first th:not(:first)").attr("colspan", classes.length); // For each classes selected
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
      //force 3 first letters to lowercase
      var classToShow =
        classes[i].substr(0, 3).toLowerCase() + classes[i].substr(3); // For each element having the class
      $("." + classToShow).each(function() {
        var index = $(this).index(); // Show selected cells in the thead
        $(".table thead tr:not(:first)").each(function() {
          $(this)
            .find("th")
            .eq(index)
            .show();
        }); // Show selected cells in the tbody
        $(".table tbody tr").each(function() {
          $(this)
            .find("td")
            .eq(index)
            .show();
        });
      });
    }
  });
  ```
- By above code i am hiding and showing the columns according to user selection
- I am using `table2export` to export the table to excel
- But the issue is when user is selecting any drop-down and then filters the table and then clicks on export that is exporting full table
- I am hiding that columns but still they are exporting

**My full code**

```js
var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 451458,
    "discount": 513,
    "GST": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 87190,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 109308,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 483194,
    "discount": 471,
    "GST": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109483,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 79305,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157660,
    "discount": 263,
    "GST": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 51059,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]

$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() { // this one to select multiple options as check box

  $("#save").show();
  $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  var sList = "";
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      sList += $(this).val() + ","
    }
  });

  $("#To").val(sList.slice(0, -1));
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});


$("#save").on("click", function() {

  // Get the selected classes
  var classes = $("#To").val().replace(/\s+/g, "").split(",");

  // Hide cells
  $(".table thead tr:not(:first) th:not(:first-child)").hide();
  $(".table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").hide();

  // Adjust thead first row colspans
  $(".table thead tr:first th:not(:first)").attr("colspan", classes.length);

  // For each classes selected
  for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    //force 3 first letters to lowercase
    var classToShow = classes[i].substr(0, 3).toLowerCase() + classes[i].substr(3);

    // For each element having the class
    $("." + classToShow).each(function() {
      var index = $(this).index();

      // Show selected cells in the thead
      $(".table thead tr:not(:first)").each(function() {
        $(this).find("th").eq(index).show();
      });

      // Show selected cells in the tbody
      $(".table tbody tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td").eq(index).show();
      });
    });
  }
});


let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) { //here i am making the header as col-span
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("discount"); //adding class to column discount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("gst"); //adding class to column gst
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net_Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("netAmount"); //adding class to column Net Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross_Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("grossAmount"); //adding class to column Gross Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);

$("#export-btn").click(function() {
  $("#dailySales").table2excel({
    filename: "Daily Sales Report.xls"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <label for="subCategoryCode">Filter Data :</label>
  <div class="input-group" id="hideFilter">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="To" id="To" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Gross Amount"> Gross Amount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Discount"> Discount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="GST"> GST
     </label></li>
        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Net Amount"> Net Amount 
     </label></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save" style="display: none;">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
     </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id="dailySales"></table>
</div>

<button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-default commonButton">
      <i class='fas fa-file-export'></i>&nbsp;Export
     </button>
```

As my code is little bit lengthy So i have commented all the lines

- For you all there is no need to check table code what i am doing after Save click is important,which i have already posted at start
- I think what going wrong is i am hiding and showing the columns which doesn't remove the column from the table that's why it is exporting the full table

If there is any other approach or what i am doing it can be done by that also, please guide me Thank-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally need to remove the hidden cells from the table before exporting. For this you need to make a copy of the table.

This is the relevant code

```
$("#export-btn").click(function() {
  var copyTable = $("#dailySales").clone(false).attr('id', '_copy_dailySales');
  copyTable.insertAfter($("#dailySales"))
  copyTable.find('td:hidden, th:hidden').remove()

  copyTable.table2excel({
    filename: "Daily Sales Report.xls"
  });
  copyTable.remove()

});
```

```js
console.clear()
var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 451458,
    "discount": 513,
    "GST": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 87190,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 109308,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 483194,
    "discount": 471,
    "GST": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109483,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 79305,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157660,
    "discount": 263,
    "GST": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 51059,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]

$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() { // this one to select multiple options as check box

  $("#save").show();
  $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  var sList = "";
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      sList += $(this).val() + ","
    }
  });

  $("#To").val(sList.slice(0, -1));
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});


$("#save").on("click", function() {

  // Get the selected classes
  var classes = $("#To").val().replace(/\s+/g, "").split(",");

  // Hide cells
  $(".table thead tr:not(:first) th:not(:first-child)").hide();
  $(".table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").hide();

  // Adjust thead first row colspans
  $(".table thead tr:first th:not(:first)").attr("colspan", classes.length);

  // For each classes selected
  for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    //force 3 first letters to lowercase
    var classToShow = classes[i].substr(0, 3).toLowerCase() + classes[i].substr(3);

    // For each element having the class
    $("." + classToShow).each(function() {
      var index = $(this).index();

      // Show selected cells in the thead
      $(".table thead tr:not(:first)").each(function() {
        $(this).find("th").eq(index).show();
      });

      // Show selected cells in the tbody
      $(".table tbody tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td").eq(index).show();
      });
    });
  }
});


let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) { //here i am making the header as col-span
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("discount"); //adding class to column discount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("gst"); //adding class to column gst
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net_Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("netAmount"); //adding class to column Net Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross_Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("grossAmount"); //adding class to column Gross Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);

$("#export-btn").click(function() {
  var copyTable = $("#dailySales").clone(false).attr('id', '_copy_dailySales');
  copyTable.insertAfter($("#dailySales"))
  copyTable.find('td:hidden, th:hidden').remove()
  
  copyTable.table2excel({
    filename: "Daily Sales Report.xls"
  });
  copyTable.remove()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <label for="subCategoryCode">Filter Data :</label>
  <div class="input-group" id="hideFilter">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="To" id="To" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Gross Amount"> Gross Amount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Discount"> Discount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="GST"> GST
     </label></li>
        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Net Amount"> Net Amount 
     </label></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save" style="display: none;">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
     </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id="dailySales"></table>
</div>

<button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-default commonButton">
      <i class='fas fa-file-export'></i>&nbsp;Export
     </button>
```

Comment: hey sir can you please help me out in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row